# Removing sundials package in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, package, ubuntu-22.04, cantera, sundials

I am trying to install Cantera 1.8 due to some reason. I have installed the latest sundial version which is not working (problem with cvodes). Now I need to remove the sundials but I am unable to do so. I have used the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get purge octave-sundials
sudo apt-get purge sundials
sudo apt-get remove sundials
```

These commands give the output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package sundial
```

How should I remove sundials, please help.

I tried to remove it and I thought it would be removed but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove octave-sundials
```

have you tried this command. normally what you did should have uninstalled but sometimes dependencies gets messed-up. it happened to me once and I was unable to uninstall that program. I had to reinstall linux again or if it doesn't stops your work let it stay in your system.

Comment: I just used it ,....it is giving the same result..                                    E: Unable to locate package sundials
E: Unable to locate package octave-sundials